# Debug Build Varient and Relese Build Varient are creating different child key name as showing in scrrenshot

Tags: database, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

After published my app on play console successfully, the app creates different child key name in firebase realtime database as showing in the attached screenshot which is very different from the debug build variant. I tried every possible solution given on google but they didn't work for me. I am also attached the Pojo or Model Class screenshot to ensure all code is good. Making class variable public as well as private are giving the same results. Hope for a positive response.

Screenshot show the different child created by debugging build variant and release build varient:

[image]

Poko or Model Class

[image]

Comment: Looks as if some obfuscation/minification is applied on the release build, which breaks the serialization.

Answer (score 0):

[Problem solved by adding PropertyName before each variable name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIkUt.jpg)